# Can't get Driver properties using IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperties on iPadOS 16.1

Tags: iokit, ipados, driverkit

We are developing our Driver using DriverKit. In client App we successfully discover our driver but can't get IORegistry properties except IOClass. So in a client App we use following code to read properties:

```
    private func debugRegistry(device: io_object_t) {
        var dictionary: Unmanaged<CFMutableDictionary>?
        IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperties(device, &dictionary, kCFAllocatorDefault, .zero)
        if let dictionary = dictionary {
            let values = dictionary.takeUnretainedValue()
            print(values)
        }
    }
```

Output is:

```
{
    IOClass = IOUserService;
}
```

We tested same code on macOS and output contains about 20+ properties. It looks like IOKi doesn't allow to read other properties except IOClass.

Environment:

- Xcode - Version 14.1 beta 2 (14B5024i).
- iPadOS - iOS 16.1 (20B5050f)

Comment: I am trying something similar and and Console.app I can see `deny(1) iokit-get-properties iokit-class:IOUSBHostDevice property:idProduct`.